# Can i remove OS X completely and install Windows?

Tags: imac, bootcamp, install, windows

Can I completely remove Mac OS X from my system and install Windows 7 or 8 on it?

I do not want to use Bootcamp or create VM's. Is there any way at all?

The problem here is that i want to ditch OSX and install Windows on my mac machine forever.

---

Will I have to buy a Windows PC?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No you don't need PC hardware since Yes you can delete OS X entirely after getting the drivers installed from Boot Camp on OS X.

Follow the directions for creating the bootcamp USB key that comes with bootcamp (you'll need an 8GB key). When you boot from the bootcamp key and it gives you disk utility just delete the OSX partition (I believe this is an option, it's been a while) And make the whole thing Winders.

The Mac **IS** an Intel PC and Bootcamp is only the drivers and whatnot to create the bootable windows installer with the Mac drivers in it.

Hold onto that key, it's your repair disk and Windows re-installer should you need to sometime in the future.

Comment: Though I usually shrink the OS X partition, but leave it there, just in case of problems I'll have a bootable OS

Comment: You can only shrink it so much. It still takes up a considerable amount of disk space

Comment: It *can* be completely removed if you like

Answer (score 0):

I've just succeeded in replacing OS X with Windows 10 on a late 2018 MacBook Pro with the touch bar.

**NOTE**: you'll need an external USB keyboard (and perhaps mouse) because MacBook's ones won't work before you install the drivers. Steps to follow:

1. Open the Boot Camp application on OS X and download the *Boot Camp Support Software*, i.e. a package containing all the Windows drivers you'll need to install and smoothly run Windows 10. You can download that package via the *Action* menu entry in the Boot Camp application.
2. Copy the content of the package to the root of a FAT32 USB pen (a 8GB pen will do the job).
3. Create a bootable USB Windows installer. I made it on another Windows 10 machine, but I guess it's possible to make it on OS X too.
4. Insert the Windows installer USB pen and reboot the MacBook Pro. Hold down the *Option* key until a boot menu appears. Boot from the Windows installer.
5. Chose the Custom installation. You'll be asked to chose the drive where to install Windows to, but you probably won't see any storage device. Hence, insert the Boot Camp drivers USB pen and press *Load drivers*. There, you can browse the pen and select the Apple SSD driver (I don't remember what is the exact folder you have to select, but it's not hard to find out).
6. Once the driver is installed, you can finally see your hard drive partitions. I deleted the OS X partition and created a new NTFS one.
7. Complete the installation. Once Windows is booted, run the *setup.exe* executable in the Boot Camp USB pen. That will install all the needed drivers (network, keyboard and touch-pad, ...).
8. Enjoy.

Comment: To the downvoter: please, justify your disappointment and suggest how to improve this answer. Don't downvote just cause you're an Apple fanboy, please. With love, from my Linux VM running inside my native Windows on the MacBook Pro.