# Create bootable Windows USB disk with Bootcamp 6

Tags: bootcamp, windows, startup, macos

I have OS X El Capitan with Bootcamp 6 in an Early 2015 Retina Macbook Pro. I want to create a bootable USB disk with Windows 10 to install it and then completely remove OS X. I have read different answers:

- [Can i remove OS X completely and install Windows?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123563/can-i-remove-os-x-completely-and-install-windows)
- [Creating A Bootable USB Of Windows 8.1 On OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103874/creating-a-bootable-usb-of-windows-8-1-on-os-x)
- [Bootable Windows 7 USB won't boot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58629/bootable-windows-7-usb-wont-boot/62700#62700)
- [How to Create a Windows 10 Installer USB Drive from Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2015/06/22/make-windows-10-install-usb-drive-from-mac-os-x/)

But I can't get my USB to show when booting and pressing the "Option" key, only my external disk with the Time Machine backup and the internal SSD is showed. I tried using Bootcamp to create a USB disk as shown here:

[image]

But with Bootcamp 6 it just asks me for an ISO and then proceeds to repartition my disk, I can't create a bootable Windows disk. I also tried using RUFUS to create a bootable Windows USB disk but it is not detected neither. Any solution or alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! I created the bootable USB with [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/), just select the Windows ISO and format the disk as FAT32. The partition scheme must be `MBR Partition Scheme for UEFI` if you select compatibility for both `BIOS` and `UEFI-CSM` it won't be detected on startup.