# Creating a bootable Windows USB drive when Bootcamp is already installed

Tags: bootcamp, usb, startup, windows

I just upgraded to El Capitan, and am now having issues booting directly into Windows. I need a bootable Windows USB stick to repair my bootcamp partition, but I'm having a difficult time making that happen.

I thought I would simply be able to use Bootcamp Assistant to create the bootable USB drive (as I did when I first install windows through Bootcamp on Yosemite), but I no longer have that option:

[image: Bootcamp Assistant]

As the above image shows, the only option I have is to remove my bootcamp partition, which is not what I want.

I've tried to manually write the ISO to the USB stick by using the terminal according to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103874/creating-a-bootable-usb-of-windows-8-1-on-os-x?lq=1) (multiple times), but it never shows on the boot menu. I've also tried [using Rufus](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214473/create-bootable-usb-disk-with-bootcamp-6?lq=1&newreg=ad892a49d4aa4499b65a99b00c5eca5b), and that shows as a bootable drive, but then I just get a black screen after I select it as the boot device.

How do I create a bootable Windows USB Drive when Bootcamp does not provide me that option? This is on a 2015 MacBook Pro, originally shipped with Yosemite and just updated to El Capitan.

UPDATE:

I was able to create a bootable USB stick by using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) with the following settings:

- Partition Scheme: GPT partition scheme for UEFI
- File System: Fat32
- Cluster Size: 4096 bytes
- Create Bootable Disk using ISO Image

  - Standard Windows Installation

Since Rufus is a Windows program, I'll keep this open in case someone can answer how to do this in OS X.